# What is the antenna gain of a mobile phone?

Tags: pcb, antenna, gsm

I'm working on a GSM/3G Project and my team has a small doubt about antenna gain selection.

All along we were using a 3dB PCB Antenna connected via U.FL/IPEX connector.
The antenna does a good job for normal areas where there is cellular connectivity but in slightly far away areas it doesn't seem to latch on to the network.

I have a Moto G (XT1033) 1st gen which latches to the network in the same region. Just to rule out my phone I tested the same site with different phones and they didn't seem to have a problem latching to the EDGE network.

So we were wondering what would the signal gain on normal cellphone antenna be?

Comment: *Just to rule out my phone I tested the same site with different phones and they didn't seem to have a problem latching to the EDGE network.* That tells you **nothing**. Are all phones using the same network ? I mean, is the distance to the basestation the same ? Are they using the same frequency band ? Some phones are more sensitive than others, this is not only determined by the antenna but also by the receiver inside the phone. There are **many** factors playing a role in this, not only the antenna.

Comment: Did they all have the same circuit internally?

Comment: Same SIM Card, Same network, Same band. 
I am using the QuectelM95 for the GSM Project, the phones have the snapdragon core for android phones and some older processor on the non smartphone devices.

Answer (score 3):

Internal antennas of mobile phones are necessarily [small](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrically_small_antenna). Gain value of small omnidirectional antennas is [theoretically limited](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/4984/RLE-TR-064-04706975.pdf), and in practice does not exceed 5dB. Gain values of 2 or 3 dB are common.

So I suppose the difference between your project and common mobile phone lies in electronics, not the antenna.